# How to use dplyr to count number?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have used pivot_longer to transform my dataset as

```
  name   value
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 A      3
2 B      2
3 C      3
4 A      2
5 B      2
6 C      3
```

I want to count `value` of each `name` as

```
value   A  B  C
1       0  0  0
2       1  2  0  
3       1  0  2
```

I wonder how to use `dplyr` to ahieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pivot_wider`:

```r
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = name,
              values_fn = length, values_fill = 0) %>% 
  complete(value = 1:3) %>% 
  replace(is.na(.), 0)

# A tibble: 3 × 4
  value     A     B     C
  <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     0     0     0
2     2     1     2     0
3     3     1     0     2
```